# How can I avoid Canvas Fingerprinting?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, anonymity, user-tracking

Canvas Fingerprinting has been getting a lot of press these last few days.
Here is a study I read on this topic: [1](https://securehomes.esat.kuleuven.be/~gacar/persistent/index.html) and [2](https://securehomes.esat.kuleuven.be/~gacar/persistent/the_web_never_forgets.pdf)

What can I do to keep browsing anonymously and avoid this tracking method?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are using Firefox you can use NoScript but right now "Canvas Fingerprinting" is really a new buzz word but when more people know about it the more developers will make addons to counter Canvas Fingerprinting.

There are several options to block Canvas fingerprinting

TOR web browser.
Yesscript.

More info here [Canvas Fingerprinting](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/07/21/companies-use-canvas-fingerprinting-track-online/)